# Distributing Pycharm projects with Modules installed in Interpreter without receivers/classmates needing to install said modules

Tags: python, pycharm, python-module, pythoninterpreter

I have installed the pyodbc, and numpy in an interpreter for the project as shown from my home computer

[image: Interpreter in Project].

I tried zipping the pycharm project in hopes that I could run it with a different computer with pycharm (without needing to install the module[since the school proxy blocks pycharm access to internet]).

I wonder if it is possible. I tried it with my friend, as I asked him to run it with the interpreter from my zip folder *\venv\scripts\python.exe*. He sent me this error

[image: Error Message].

Note: I'm using python 3.7, idk if he just accidentally selected 2.7.

**My question is, Is there a way to distribute my project without receivers/classmates needing to download the package into their pycharm provided that I have the modules installed in the interpreter** as show in this directory

[image: Directory of Interpreter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you package a virtual environment along with your code (your `venv` folder), then the recipient only needs to select the environment upon receiving it and opening the project in PyCharm. Once the project is open, go to `Settings -> Project: ... -> Project Interpreter -> Add -> Add` and select the folder containing the virtual environment under the 'Existing Environment' option.

[image: PyCharm Add Python Interpreter]